# Force i18n locale for activerecord errors in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization

I have a rails 5 app, in dev, I am using i18n and locales can be set by the user in the URL with the following code in the `application_controller`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_locale

  private

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || session[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    session[:locale] = I18n.locale
  end
end
```

In some case I am getting errors in my logs like
`translation missing: fr.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid`
This specific i18n translation would actually give the error but since the locale is not found, I cannot see the error.

I would like to avoid importing the locales for activerecord errors (and eventually) because at one point, I'll be handling errors for users in a locale I dont understand.

How can I enforce errors (or other specific i18n keys) to use the `:en` locale for i18n ?

note : Currently, the i18n dont revert to a default locale if it misses, I wish to keep this behavior, at least for every translation served by the views.

edit: sample log

```
Started POST "/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-17 14:35:39 +0100
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  [...]
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 73ms (ActiveRecord: 15.2ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (translation missing: fr.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid):

app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:45:in `block in create'
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:44:in `create'
Started GET "/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-17 14:36:02 +0100
```

Comment: `translation missing` appearing in your logs IS the error, and it isn't translated. What is it you're missing, do you want to see why the record was invalid? Are you currently writing translated activerecord errors to your log? What is your actual original goal?

Comment: My goal is to see why the record is invalid. The record_invalid key is not found for this locale (https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/7416877aa3132a3f627cc01f872720decf806cc2/rails/locale/en.yml#L6). the locale translation should actually give the error since it has `%{errors}` but since it is not there, the logs do not display the error.

Comment: But if you are logging the errors, just log the errors - not the translation. If you don't want to add translations then you shouldn't use them. You certainly shouldn't use translations in your logs, that's just strange.

Comment: precision: I am not explicitly requesting the log message, my guess is that activerecord would actually throw the error (like if a validation failed). ex:
 `Started POST "/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-17 14:35:39 +0100
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  [...]
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 73ms (ActiveRecord: 15.2ms)


  
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (translation missing: fr.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid):
  
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:45:in `block in create'
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:44:in `create' `